# creating branch out of branch

Tags: git, version-control, merge, branch

suppose I have master

suppose I do `git branch branchA master`
then I do development on branchA
then I want to create another branch from branchA so I do `git branch branchB branchA`
and then I continue development on both branchA AND branchB with each branches having their own stuff developed into it
My question is:

Suppose I ultimately want to merge both branchA and branchB to master once development is done. 
Suppose I do a whole bunch of `git pull origin master` on BOTH branchA and branch B. 
And suppose that sometimes I want to merge between branch A and branch B.

1. Will the changes for `git pull origin master` in the separate branches conflict with each other whenever I try to merge in between branches or when I ultimately merge the branches to master in the final product.
2. Will doing this branching and separate development make it hard to merge in between branches (branchA and branchB)...ie, will this unnecessarily increase the chances of conflict when I try to merge between branchA and branchB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't completely understand what you are doing, but I'd suggest the following:

- If you branch off branchA from master, better develop there and merge back into master. Don't integrate master into branchA. If required, rebase branchA on top of master
- Better don't branch off branchA, or if you do, consider branchA frozen (now branchB depends on its history...). In such a case, merge branchB back into branchA and the result into master.

I'm not saying it can't be done in other ways, but I know for a fact that any more mesh-like graph shown by gitk will get me terminally confused. Keep it simple, handling VCS is complex enough as is.